# Flutter use ProxyProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

#### Description

I have a page(**InitialElementResultScreen**) that has to wait for several operations to be done in the **InitialElementResultNotifier** to display the rest of the page.

#### Code that works

**My InitialElementResultScreen:**

```
class InitialElementResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  InitialElementResultScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarWidget.withoutMenu(title: title),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context){

    // => For use variable in my screen I use the notifier.
    var _initialElementResultProvider = Provider.of<InitialElementResultNotifier>(context);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ContainerComponent(
            colorContainer: AppColors.backgroundLightBasic,
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: _initialElementResultProvider.myFuture,
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text('loading');
                    }else{
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          // ... some widgets
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  }
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**When I call my InitialElementResultScreen** :

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<InitialElementResultNotifier>(
    create: (BuildContext context) => InitialElementResultNotifier(getData: data)
)
```

My **InitialElementResultNotifier** receives external data directly in its constructor. It converts them to objects so that I can do operations on them.

**My InitialElementResultNotifier :**

```
class InitialElementResultNotifier with ChangeNotifier{

  // External Notifier
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  FormInitialElementModel dataReceived;
  Future myFuture;

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  InitialElementResultNotifier({
    @required String getData,
  }){
    _initialise(getData);
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise(String getData) async{
    print('--- initialise');

    dataReceived = await _convertDataReceived(getData);
    myFuture = loadingInitialElementData();
  }

  // Functions public
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future<void> loadingInitialElementData() async
  {
    print('---------------------- dataReceived');
    print(dataReceived); // => I see my data in the console
    // ... some operations
  }
}
```

#### Code that does not work

In my function which **loadingInitialElementData ()**, I would like to have access to another notifier. The notifier **LoaderNotifier** manages the display of different messages depending on its state that I will change according to my operations in the **loadingInitialElementData()** function.

For this I will use a proxy Provider. So now I call my **InitialElementResultScreen** like that:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<LoaderNotifier>(
    create: (BuildContext context) => LoaderNotifier()
),
ProxyProvider<LoaderNotifier, InitialElementResultNotifier>(
    update: (BuildContext context, LoaderNotifier loaderNotifier, InitialElementResultNotifier initialElementResultNotifier) {
      return InitialElementResultNotifier(
          getData: data,
          loaderNotifier: loaderNotifier
      );
    }
),
```

I will update my **InitialElementResultNotifier**:

All the code is the same except 3 lines to be able to call on my other Notifier. I marked the lines as comments in the code

```
class InitialElementResultNotifier with ChangeNotifier{

  // External Notifier
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  LoaderNotifier _loaderNotifier; // => New line !

  // Variables
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  FormInitialElementModel dataReceived;
  Future myFuture;

  // Constructor
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  InitialElementResultNotifier({
    @required String getData,
    LoaderNotifier loaderNotifier, // => New line !
  }){
    _loaderNotifier = loaderNotifier; // => New line !
    _initialise(getData);
  }

  // Initialisation
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future _initialise(String getData) async{
    print('--- initialise');

    dataReceived = await _convertDataReceived(getData);
    myFuture = loadingInitialElementData();
  }

  // Functions public
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Future<void> loadingInitialElementData() async
  {
    print('---------------------- dataReceived');
    print(dataReceived); // => I see my data in the console
    // ... some operations
  }
}
```

#### Error

I don't understand why I've this error, what is my mistake ?

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building InitialElementResultScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<InitialElementResultNotifier>]):
Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (InitialElementResultNotifier).


This is likely a mistake, as Provider will not automatically update dependents
when InitialElementResultNotifier is updated. Instead, consider changing Provider for more specific
implementation that handles the update mechanism, such as:

- ListenableProvider
- ChangeNotifierProvider
- ValueListenableProvider
- StreamProvider

Alternatively, if you are making your own provider, consider using InheritedProvider.

If you think that this is not an error, you can disable this check by setting
Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType to `null` in your main file:
```

Comment: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/396

Comment: I don't understand it is mentioned to use ChangeNotifierProvider instead of Provider, which I did !

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you, but I feel I'm having a hard time following along. One thing I noticed however that might help is that in `InitialElementResultNotifier` `myFuture` is declared, but not initialized, and no where in that class you are calling `notifyListeners` therefore in `InitialElementResultScreen` `build` will not be called when the `dataReceived` and `myFuture` finally receive values or change. But the whole idea of using a `FutureBuilder` in conjunction with `Provider` feels very wrong to me. If you are to proceed with this particular design you need to look into [Completers](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-async/Completer-class.html) but I advice you against it.

Comment: myFuture is initialized in the "_initialize()" function. 
In my FutureBuilder instead of directly calling it to the "loadingInitialElementData()" function, I go through the myFuture function. This is supposed to avoid FutureBuilder double calls ... shouldn't you do that?


I don't understand why the provider is not good to do this? 
In the futureBuilder, instead in addition to putting the CircularProgressIndicator, I want to put a sentence that displays the progress of my loading status.

Comment: When you get a new instant of `InitialElementResultNotifier` in the 
 `ChangeNotifierProvider` callback, you will get an initial `null` value for `myFuture`. Then there is a race condition between getting that initial value in `_initialise` and the `FutureBuilder` It maybe the case that you haven't experienced an error due to this race condition yet, but you could. If you need to to something like this where you fire up an async request and use it later. You must either await for it to complete which you are not doing since `_initialise` is called in the constructor or use a `Completer`

Comment: Another point is that you are not calling `notifyListeners` after `myFuture` is set so if you reach the `FutureBuilder` before that async is done you will get `null` as your `future` which may cause an undesirable effect, and after `myFuture` is set that will have no affect on your code in itself.